# MongoDB Array Data removing

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

This  is the data I have, I want to remove the the array of that particular monitorId when it matches the User Id

```
  {
       "_id" : ObjectId("5afd8d562b2de0034953fdae"),
       "isActiveEnabled" : true,
       "isFrEnabled" : null,
       "isDriveEnabled" : true,
       "organization" : "5747f009544abb2ecbccae5f",
       "monitorList" : [
           {
               "timeFailSmsAlert" : false,
               "emailAlert" : true,
               "alcoholSmsAlert" : true,
               "failEmailAlert" : false,
               "displayName" : "t",est
               "username" : "test",
               "monitorId" : "5748fcb6c9e3deeb30d8c74f",
               "organization" : "5747f009544abb2ecbccae5f"
           }
       ],
       "userId" : "5afd8d542b2de0034953fdac"
    }
```

This is my query:

```
db.getCollection("userconfigs").update({'userId':'5b2f276ea93966a93474006e'},{$pull:{'monitorlist':{'monitorId':'5b30a4002dea1a0fd6597b79'}}})
```

This is the output I got , Basically I want to remove

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Comment: is it objectId or string?

Comment: It is string @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: I think you need `$elemMatch` here.

Comment: `db.getCollection("userconfigs").update({'userId':'5b2f276ea93966a93474006e'},{$pull:{'monitorlist':{$elemMatch:{'monitorId':'5b30a4002dea1a0fd6597b79'}}}})`

Comment: tried that too, but t didn't work @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @SrikanthDoddi: monitorlist vs monitorList - pay more attention.

Comment: @SrikanthDoddi: if you fix that, your original update also should work. No need for elemMatch here, it seems.

Comment: Yeah, it worked after fixing the monitorList to Capital L thanks @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the variable from monitorlist to monitorList solved the issue, thanks.